# Why does tensorflow operation lead to NaN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan, loss

When I call tf.reduce_sum() or tf.nn.l2_loss(), I get NaN as result, why is that so?

I have tried something like this:

```py
sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(tf.clip_by_value(forward,1e-10,1.0)))
Out[18]: nan
```

but the result is also nan..

```py
forward
Out[17]: 
array([[0.93465865],
       [0.96060896],
       [0.9346889 ],
       ...,
       [0.97003865],
       [0.9155061 ],
       [0.94954056]], dtype=float32)

expected
Out[10]: 
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       ...,
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32)

sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(forward))
Out[14]: nan

resultToPrint = tf.nn.l2_loss(forward - expected+1e-8, name="squared_error_cost")
ergebnis = sess.run(resultToPrint)
```

ergebnis is also NaN..

The expected result is NOT NaN, but an actual result. As I am very new to TensorFlow, I really would appreciate any good advise and explanations, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `forward` has any nan values. Since `nan + float == nan`, I assume reduce_mean is just propagating it along the whole axis.